# Form submit not working in IE 11

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer

In my Rails 4 project I'm using a bootstrap_form_tag to allow the user to select whether the notes of a profile should be included when generating a pdf for printing. This is all working as expected in the latest distributions of Chrome/Firefox/Edge and Safari but not in IE 11 (haven't tried any other browsers yet).

When I check the network traffic using Firefox the get method is called properly, but in IE nothing happens, no request is made to the server at all.

This is the form I am using:

```
  <%= bootstrap_form_tag(url: profile_path(@profile), method: :get) do |f| %>
    <%= f.form_group do %>
      <%= f.check_box :notes, label: t('.include_notes') %>
    <% end %>
    <%= button_tag(type: "submit", class: "btn btn-default", name: 'format', value: 'pdf') do %>
      <%= t('.print_out') %>
      <span class= "glyphicon glyphicon-print"></span>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

I believe the part IE can't handle lies here somewhere since I cant detect any request made to the server when the button is clicked. My back end implementation seems to be working just fine since a regular link_to to the the same controller action works fine in IE too.

Any suggestions will be appreciated!

Comment: Can you post the actual HTML generated on IE?

Comment: When checking the generated HTML it looks like the div ending the form is placed before the button. I will check this and see if that is causing the error. If not I will post the full code

Comment: That was the issue! The HTML generated looks different in IE than in the other browsers which causes the button to end up outside the form div.